# I gave my APT repository the highest priority, why aren't the latest packages being installed from it?

Tags: debian, apt

Using apt-pinning I gave [my openSUSE Build Service (OBS) repository](https://build.opensuse.org/project/show/home:fusion809) the highest priority of 1003 (where 1000 is given to the official stretch repositories) and specified the packages I want from it, yet for some reason Debian 9 is using an older version of my Vim-related packages (namely 8.0.1520 vs the latest I've packaged at the time of writing, 8.0.1587). If you want to see the APT configs in /etc/apt that I have not just left as the defaults [here they are](https://github.com/fusion809/apt-settings). [Here](http://paste.debian.net/1013542/) is the output of `apt show -a vim`.

EDIT:

`apt show -a vim-common | grep 587`

reveals that vim-common 8.0.1587 doesn't seem to be available. But https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/fusion809/Debian_9.0/all/ does have a vim-common package for version 8.0.1587, so I think this is an OBS issue.

EDIT2:

`apt-cache policy` returns: https://pastebin.com/5yusCSG1.

`apt-cache policy vim-common` returns:

```
vim-common:
  Installed: 2:8.0.1520-1
  Candidate: 2:8.0.1520-1
  Version table:
     2:8.0.1587-1 500
        500 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/fusion809/Debian_9.0  Packages
 *** 2:8.0.1520-1 1003
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:8.0.1453-1 1003
          2 http://debian.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/debian sid/main amd64 Packages
          2 http://debian.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
     2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u1 1003
       1000 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
     2:7.4.488-7+deb8u3 1003
          2 http://debian.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/debian oldstable/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Add the output of `apt-cache policy` and `apt-cache policy vim-common`, please

Comment: Done. I have also asked for help at the #opensuse-buildservice IRC channel on freenode.

Comment: Looking at the output, it's clear that whatever pinning you used, it was not on the repo. And I don't see any mention of the openSUSE repo in your `preferences` either. What exactly do you mean by the first line of your question, then?

Comment: It was, the `a=/` in the preferences file ([line 14](https://github.com/fusion809/apt-settings/blob/debian-9/preferences#L14)) that refers to this repository. After all look at how the OBS repo is mentioned in [sources.list.d/fusion809.list](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fusion809/apt-settings/debian-9/sources.list.d/fusion809.list). It's labelled `/`.

Comment: Check the output of `apt-cache policy`. See the `o=obs://build.opensuse.org/home:fusion809/Debian_9.0,n=Debian_9.0,l=home:fusion809,c=`? That's how that repo should have been identified in `preferences`.

Comment: So I should use `a=obs://build.opensuse.org/home:fusion809/Debian_9.0,n=Debian_9.0,l=home:fusion809,c=`? Or home:fusion809? Sorry for my ignorance I was trying to get this right. The apt-pinning docs I read seamed to just assume I knew how to refer to repos in the `a=` line, so I followed what patterns I could see.

Comment: Ah use `o=obs://build.opensuse.org/home:fusion809/Debian_9.0,n=Debian_9.0,l=home:fusion809,c=`. Tried it and it's working.

Comment: Just `o=obs://build.opensuse.org/home:fusion809/Debian_9.0` should be enough to identify this repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify a repository in the `preferences` file, use the output of `apt-cache policy`, or the information from its `Release` file:

```
~ apt-cache policy 
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gophers/archive/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-gophers-archive,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Go 1.X packages,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google, Inc.,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main,b=amd64
     origin dl.google.com
 500 ftp://ftp.iitb.ac.in//os/ubuntu/archives/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin ftp.iitb.ac.in
```

Use a combination of `o`,`a`, etc. values that identify the repo to sufficient uniqueness. The same information can be obtained from the `Release` or `InRelease` files of the repository channels and components. For example, the `main` component of the `stable` channel of Google's repo (`https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Release`) has:

```
Archive: stable
Version: 1.0
Component: main
Origin: Google, Inc.
Label: Google
Architecture: amd64
Description: Google chrome-linux repository.
```

Note that `a=/` wouldn't work in your case, since your repo sets a different value for `Archive`:

```
Archive: Debian_9.0
Codename: Debian_9.0
Origin: obs://build.opensuse.org/home:fusion809/Debian_9.0
Label: home:fusion809
```